# unable to sum from active cell to its above range cell values

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently at cell say H37 which is my active cell and will keep on changing dynamically.
I want to sum using a range from H37 with its above cells H36 +H35..till H3(last integer value)

I tried something like this but it doesnt work:

```
Dim rng As Range         
Set rng = Range(ActiveCell & H3)                   

Range("F3") = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)
```

I wanted the sum in F3 .

Also tried like---

```
 WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(ActiveCell, .End(xlUp)))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Try this: `Set rng = Range("h3", ActiveCell)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim InitialCell As String
Dim FinalCell As String


InitialCell = "H3"
FinalCell = ActiveCell.Address

Range("F3").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(" & InitialCell & ":" & FinalCell & ")"

End Sub
```

You can adjust the InitialCell if you want to sum starting from somewhere other than H3, and the FinalCell represents that activecell's address.  This works by converting the cell locations into strings and writing a formula in cell F3 that takes these string cell-locations and sums across them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Set rng = Range("H3:" & ActiveCell.address)
```

Which will set the address correctly.

You might find this interesting though:

```
dim myRngStr as string
myRngStr = "H3:" & ActiveCell.address
msgbox myRngStr
Set rng = Range(myRngStr)
```

As it will show the actual address you are looking for.

Comment: Yes it shows the msg H3:$H$37.but i am unable to get the sum in the destination cell F3.

Comment: MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)gives me 0

Comment: `Range("F3").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng)`

Comment: Thanks @ Ken and @enderland. Your answers help!!